# How to publish an Add-On for Calendar as such?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I'm developing a script which modifies events with certain criteria, I was able to publish it as Docs Add-On, and there are other options, but no Calendar. [This guys](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/uberconference_for_google_calendar/255217867751) nailed, but Calendar is not even as option in the G Suit Makerplace SDK (I managed Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

From a post by [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) on [this Google+ conversation](https://plus.google.com/+MartinHawksey/posts/gqQHDp18Afb)

> Thanks for the feedback. At the moment the add-on framework only allows a developer to add a custom conference provider (this WebEx, etc), which isn't really applicable to a mass audience. If and when the framework become more general purpose I'll push the product team to make it generally available, since I'm sure there is a lot of great functionality this community can add to the Google Calendar experience.